# Ask a contributor for citation

Tags: discussion, etiquette

In academic practice and code of conduct, it is fair to obligatory to mention authors and sources of information. Some of the contributions on this site merit to be cited. However, the authors are anonymous. Is there a way to contact the authors whether he or she would appeciate to be cited in a non-public conversation?

Comment: Forwarded this to Global Meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361543/ask-a-contributor-for-citation

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to proceed here.

1. I agree with @curiousdannii that most academic institutions will accept a quote or citation from any source provided it is appropriately documented with references internally
2. Some of the users here have contact information in their profile section and welcome private contact
3. For those who wish to remain anonymous, it is possible to ask the person to contact you by leaving your contact information either in a comment or in your profile.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just comment below their answer asking how they would like to be cited.

If they never reply, then you can cite them using their username/pseudonym here.

Comment: But you do not cite an anonymous author

Comment: @Jeschu Everyone here can be identified by username, even those who have the default userXXXXX names. And most people pick a pseudonym.

Comment: I suppose the majority of the users here are professional theologists, some of them professors or Ph.D. students. In a publication, you would not cite or mention thanks to curiousdannii on stack exchange but a real person.

Comment: @Jeschu Actually probably the majority of users here are not academics (and if they are, theology is a different discipline to Biblical studies.) There are lots of regular lay people, some religious workers, some Bible college students. In any case, academics are used to citing weird things. If an idea that is useful to you comes from some website, then you cite it with whatever author name that website uses. There's absolutely nothing wrong with citing a username from this site in a professional research article. But as I said, try asking first. They'll probably tell you their name.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

A number of contributors also have included on their profile page links to their contact information, or to a website they run, which in turn would provide a means of private correspondence.